# Why does a for loop not reach the number set in the 2nd condition of the loop?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, int, increment

I don't understand why, in a for loop, using an int - if it's initialised as 0 and you set the loop to increment the int for integer less than a figure - if you output the integer each time the loop executes - it doesn't go up to the figure you told it to increment up to in the for loop.

I might not be phrasing myself very clearly here to best help you understand so please see the following link by way of an example:

http://codepad.org/doPC6kuI

The output in the link is 0,1,2,3,4 - I realise it's 5 ints but int i begins at 0 but is incremented before the output so I don't understand why the first output is 0 and not 1 making it 1,2,3,4,5.

It's annoying me that I can't rationalise this or come up with a logical explanation.

Comment: Because the update-clause isn't executed until the body of the loop has finished. the order of operation is 1. init, 2. test (and break if false), 3. body, 4. update, then goto (2). Any of these steps will be skipped if not provided in the for-construct.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to post the relevant code here instead of off-site. All questions asked here should be self-contained, including all relevant information. Having the meaningful part of your question elsewhere means that if the off-site location is unavailable for some reason, your question is unclear. (It's also not useful in a search by future readers trying to solve their problems.) Thanks. (I did **not** downvote your question, BTW.)

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop in your example works as follows:

1. Initialise `i = 0`
2. Repeat while `i < 5` is true:

   1. Execute the body of the `for` loop
   2. Increment `i`

The condition is checked at the beginning of each iteration and the increment happens at the end of each iteration.

So first `i` is initialised to `0`, then it is checked that `0 < 5`, which is fine, so we start the first iteration. At the end of the iteration, `i` gets incremented to `1`, then it checks that `1 < 5` and we start the second iteration, and so on. At the end of the 5th iteration, `i` gets incremented to `5`, and it checks that `5 < 5`, which is not true any more, so no more iterations occur. So no iteration occurs in which `i` has value `5`.

Answer (score 0):

You said it yourself:

> you set the loop to increment the int for integer **less than** a figure

If you do that, the loop will only run for values less then the limit, not the limit itself. The counter is incremented **after** each loop, and **before** checking the condition; so it's 0 for the first iteration, 1 for the second, and so on; then the condition stops it before the iteration when it would be 5.

If you wanted to include the limit, then you'd loop while it's **less than or equal** the limit.